# SQL Subquery returned more than 1 value - on execution error

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2008, stored-procedures

I'm trying to update a `trade` table in `surveillance` database from another `trade` table in `CSD_4_00` using a stored procedure as follows:

```
USE [CSD_4_00]

GO
CREATE PROCEDURE [dbo].[TradeData]
AS
BEGIN
    UPDATE [surveillance].[dbo].Trade 
    SET SellerMarketMember = (SELECT [SellerMember].[MemberCode]
                                FROM Trade
                                INNER JOIN [Member] As SellerMember ON Trade.[SellerMarketMemberId] = [SellerMember].[MemberId])
    , SellerAccount = (SELECT [SellerAccount].[AccountNumber]
                        FROM Trade
                        INNER JOIN [Account] As SellerAccount ON Trade.[SellerAccountId] = [SellerAccount].[AccountId])
    , BuyerMarketMember = (SELECT [BuyerMember].[MemberCode]
                            FROM Trade
                            INNER JOIN [Member] As BuyerMember ON Trade.[BuyerMarketMemberId] = [BuyerMember].[MemberId])
    , BuyerAccount = (SELECT [BuyerAccount].[AccountNumber]
                        FROM Trade
                        INNER JOIN [Account] As BuyerAccount ON Trade.[BuyerAccountId] = [BuyerAccount].[AccountId])
    , CancelTime = (SELECT CancelTime
                        FROM Trade)

    WHERE [surveillance].[dbo].Trade.[Ticket] = (SELECT TicketNumber FROM Trade )

END
GO
```

but on execution it resulted in the following error:

> Subquery returned more than 1 value. This is not permitted when the subquery follows =, !=, <, <= , >, >= or when the subquery is used as an expression.

So, I tried to get round the problem using this modified version of my procedure:

```
CREATE PROCEDURE [dbo].[TradeData]
AS
BEGIN
    -- SET NOCOUNT ON added to prevent extra result sets from
    -- interfering with SELECT statements.
    SET NOCOUNT ON;

    -- Insert statements for procedure here
    UPDATE [surveillance].[dbo].Trade 
    SET SellerMarketMember = [SellerMember].[MemberCode]
                                FROM Trade as T
                                INNER JOIN [Member] As SellerMember ON T.[SellerMarketMemberId] = [SellerMember].[MemberId]
    WHERE [surveillance].[dbo].Trade.[Ticket] in(SELECT TicketNumber FROM Trade )

    UPDATE [surveillance].[dbo].Trade set SellerAccount =  [SellerAccount].[AccountNumber]
                        FROM Trade as T
                        INNER JOIN [Account] As SellerAccount ON T.[SellerAccountId] = [SellerAccount].[AccountId]
    WHERE [surveillance].[dbo].Trade.[Ticket] in(SELECT TicketNumber FROM Trade )

    UPDATE [surveillance].[dbo].Trade set BuyerMarketMember = [BuyerMember].[MemberCode]
                            FROM Trade as T
                            INNER JOIN [Member] As BuyerMember ON T.[BuyerMarketMemberId] = [BuyerMember].[MemberId]
    WHERE [surveillance].[dbo].Trade.[Ticket] in(SELECT TicketNumber FROM Trade )


    UPDATE [surveillance].[dbo].Trade set BuyerAccount = [BuyerAccount].[AccountNumber]
                        FROM Trade as T
                        INNER JOIN [Account] As BuyerAccount ON T.[BuyerAccountId] = [BuyerAccount].[AccountId]
    WHERE [surveillance].[dbo].Trade.[Ticket] in(SELECT TicketNumber FROM Trade )


UPDATE [surveillance].[dbo].Trade set    CancelTime =  T.CancelTime FROM Trade as T
                        WHERE [surveillance].[dbo].Trade.[Ticket] in(SELECT TicketNumber FROM Trade )                       

END
GO
```

No errors appeared on execution, but I got wrong results in my table. 
Any help?

Comment: The problem you have is that in at least one of the UPDATEs your subselect or JOIN is returning more than one row, so TicketNumber is not unique in the Trade table - you need to make the predicate return exactly 1 or 0 rows.

Answer (score 0):

Hopefully this will give you the right result.

It will make your script valid:

```
CREATE PROCEDURE [dbo].[TradeData]
AS
BEGIN
    UPDATE Trade
    SET SellerMarketMember = 
        (SELECT TOP 1 [SellerMember].[MemberCode]
         FROM [Member] As SellerMember 
         WHERE Trade.[SellerMarketMemberId] = [SellerMember].[MemberId])
    , SellerAccount = 
        (SELECT TOP 1 [SellerAccount].[AccountNumber]
         FROM [Account] As SellerAccount 
         WHERE Trade.[SellerAccountId] = [SellerAccount].[AccountId])
    , BuyerMarketMember = 
        (SELECT TOP 1 [BuyerMember].[MemberCode]
         FROM [Member] As BuyerMember 
         WHERE Trade.[BuyerMarketMemberId] = [BuyerMember].[MemberId])
    , BuyerAccount = 
        (SELECT TOP 1 [BuyerAccount].[AccountNumber]
         FROM [Account] As BuyerAccount 
         WHERE Trade.[BuyerAccountId] = [BuyerAccount].[AccountId])
         -- CancelTime looks strange. I can't tell what you are trying
    , CancelTime = 
      (SELECT CancelTime
       FROM Trade)
    FROM [surveillance].[dbo].Trade Trade
    WHERE [surveillance].[dbo].Trade.[Ticket] in (SELECT TicketNumber FROM Trade )

END
```

Comment: This will make the first script syntactically safe but it doesn't address the issue of multiple values being SELECTed for the UPDATE - it just takes 1 of them, not necessarily the right one, as reflected in the OPs 2nd attempt.

Comment: But what it does do is join the tables in the subselect as it should have been joined

Comment: Agreed, it is a step in the right direction, but it's misleading to say "Hopefully this will give you the right result.".

Comment: This is the best effort with the given information. It should solve the wrong data and it should give the same result as the attempted query

Answer (score 0):

To give a proper answer, it would help if you could give an idea of what these tables (Trade, Member, etc.) are. It appears to me that Member, etc. are meant to be master tables and Trade a transaction table - and you are trying to update the transaction table with details from the master tables. If this is the case, one point occurs to me:

```
SELECT [SellerMember].[MemberCode]
                            FROM Trade
                            INNER JOIN [Member] As SellerMember ON Trade.[SellerMarketMemberId] = [SellerMember].[MemberId]
```

Surely, the Trade table will have multiple records with the same seller member and therefore, that is why the subquery returns multiple records?

If `[SellerMember].[MemberCode]`, etc. are indeed meant to be unique values, as I would expect,  `select TOP 1` as suggested above (or `select distinct`) should give the right behavior.